# Twitter bootstrap - avoid resizing inside modal

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

All experts in Twitter bootstrap will know that you have a responsive way to fit the things in the screen. If you use that css class, all elements will resize on window resizing.

The problem for me comes with the elements place inside a Modal.

Modal won't resize, but its elements inside will. And the result is that when I resize the window, the elements don't fit anymore in the modal.

Did anyone pass through this?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it.

When modal is opened, disable the link tag that contains the load of bootstrap-responsive.css.

One can use jQuery for that:

```
<link id="lnk_twitter_boostrap-responsive" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

$("#lnk_twitter_bootstrap-responsive").attr("disabled", true);
```

Don't forget to enable it back when close the Modal.

Remember that this will cause the "responsibility" not to work while the modal is opened. So you'll have to be responsible yourself.